# Rank of a transformation matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f:\Bbb{R}^m\to\Bbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation. As is common knowledge, it can be expressed as an $n\times m$ matrix.

My book says that the rank of the matrix should also be $n$. I can't understand why that is.

Comment: This is only necessarily true if we know a little bit more about $f$ (e.g. that $f$ is surjective).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom- I thought the same.

Answer (score 2):

This matrix  say $A$ has the rank $n$ if $f$ is surjective i.e. $\operatorname{Im}f=\Bbb R^n$ and in the general case we see by the rank-nullity theorem that
$$\operatorname{rank}A\le \min(n,m)$$